# Why will Geopandas not read geopackage into dataframe?

Tags: geopandas, geopackage, python-3, geodataframe

I am trying to read in a geopackage as a dataframe using `Geopandas`. I am using `Python 3.8, Geopandas 0.10.2, and Fiona 1.8.20`. The geopackage I was using to test this is publicly available in any of the zip files [here](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/TopoMapVector/OK/GPKG/). Here's my code, which works fine on another machine with the exact same package versions (I have tried running this in VS Code and Jupyter notebook using the same env).

```
import os
import fiona
import geopandas as gp

fdb_file_path = r'C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Projects\testing\VECTOR_Achille_OK_7_5_Min_GPKG.gpkg'
target_layer_name = 'CellGrid_7_5Minute'

os.path.exists(fdb_file_path)

existing_layer = gp.read_file(fdb_file_path, layer=target_layer_name)
```

When I run this in a Jupyter Notebook, it completely kills the kernel and restarts it without any error message. When I run it in VS Code, the error says `can't read geopackage. [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` Any clues as to what's going on here. I've tried multiple geopackages from the above site (to make sure one wasn't corrupt) with the same results. I am wondering is this is a `geopandas` issue.

Comment: Can you try reading it with `pyogrio` engine? `conda install -c conda-forge pyogrio` and then set `engine="pyogrio"` in `read_file`. (requires latest geopandas)

Comment: I installed and set the engine to pyogrio as suggested. I'm still getting the same error: `[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. The debugger just exits without any other error. I'm starting to think this is not package related, but something else.

Comment: _"which works fine on another machine with the exact same package versions"_, so it's something with the machine. I would start by checking the machine logs. I don't think the problem is in any way related to any GIS component.

Comment: Correct. I was able to resolve this issue by creating a new env using conda with fresh geopandas installation. In my previous env, I had installed Jupyter Lab from condaforge after geopandas. This created some sort of dependency conflict (although I am not sure exactly what); hence why it worked in a notebook. Once I installed a new env without Jupyter Lab, it worked fine in VS Code.